# Program version using the database?

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to get more information about the program using an Oracle database except from the exe-name? I would like to have the exes version number and/or hash code or something else that allows me to uniquely distinguish one exe-file-version from another.

I don't necessary need to find this info in program code, an admin tool like Toad och Sql Developer would do fine.

Comment: What are you trying to do? On what O/S platform?

Comment: Haven't heard of anything like that. Remember that this information is stuff that the client is telling Oracle. For a security point of view, it shouldn't be trusted. And sometimes all you'll get back is that it is something using JDBC.

Comment: Is Windows, both on server and clients. What I would like to do is to find out if someone is using an old client version against the db, without deploying new client software, only use what's already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to change the exe-s in question (ie is in an internal app)?

If so, you could set the version number using the DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO package...

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO

Comment: At this time, I can't change the exes. I'm hoping that maybe some kind of exe-unique info is transferred to the db server.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to reliably get the info you want is to find the OS process ID (v$session) and then use a ps or something like taskmanager.exe to get detail from the client systems OS.

It sounds cumbersome but is scriptable if you have suffient rights on the client app's hosts.